# MFC : CFileDialog and admin shares

Tags: mfc, network-shares

I force the open file dialog to start with the initial directory as \\servername, once it opens I want it to show all the admin shares(C$, D$). How do I achieve this? Admin shares will always be available on my servers. Eventually the user will select a file from this network path.

Comment: I don't think you can see the admin shares as C$ etc. with CFileDialog or with the Win32 GetOpenFileName function.

Comment: you can force it to start with \\Servername\c$